# Passing Values from a ModalViewController to the host ViewController

Tags: xcode4

I have a screen (Client_Info) that calls a modal view controller (ModalClient) that has three toggle buttons. Once a user cycles through the three possible choices for each button I want the ModalClient screen to send the values of said buttons to the "host" screen i.e. the screen that called the modal view controller. Unless I'm confused I believe this would be done in the same way one would send values from one view controller to another. The following is my code:

**ModalClient**

Client_Info *NewView = [[Client_Info alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

```
NewView.PropP1 = buttonD1;
NewView.PropP2 = buttonD2;
NewView.PropP3 = buttonD3;

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Client_Info (Host)**
PropP1 to PropP3 all have been made properties in Client_Info.h and have been synthesized in Client_Info.m file. I can conclude the code if need be.

Thanks in advance.